# NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException when two table has same column names

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables `Item` and `Nikasa` - whose definitions looks like:

`Item { id, name, spec}` and `Nikasa {id, date, item_id}.` Here `item_id` represents `Item.id`.

I did a simple native SQL join to select only `Item.id` and `Nikasa.id` as:

```
Session s = getSession();
SQLQuery sq = s.createSQLQuery("SELECT it.id, nik.id FROM item it LEFT JOIN nikasa nik ON (it.id = nik.item_id)");
List result = sq.list();
```

But I am getting exception `NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException : Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query` at line `List result=sq.list();`:

**Stack-trace :**

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:594)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1986)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1585)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
```

Can you please suggest what's wrong going on?

Comment: It looks like I solved it.  `SELECT it.id as iid, nik.id as nid` did the mystery.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need set the result alias.

```
SELECT it.id as itemid, nik.id as nikasaid FROM item it LEFT JOIN nikasa nik ON (it.id = nik.item_id)
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting the exception in Hibernate 3. Which version you have tested? could you please confirm. Thanks, Kathir

Comment: What if i want to get all columns as result and not some columns?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your query in SQL workbench you will find that the table name is same as id for two columns. Hibernate treats it as duplicated so an alias is required.
Let us assume you have query:

```
SELECT it.id, nik.id FROM item it LEFT JOIN nikasa nik ON (it.id = nik.item_id)
```

Output of the column name on SQL workbench will be:

```
id | id |
```

which works correctly there.
But for hibernate it needs unique column name. So you need to add alias in anyone of the column

```
SELECT it.id as it_id, nik.id FROM item it LEFT JOIN nikasa nik ON (it.id = nik.item_id)
```

or

```
SELECT it.id , nik.id as nik_id FROM item it LEFT JOIN nikasa nik ON (it.id = nik.item_id)
```

or giving both of the column an alias.