# native query SELECT multiple table hibernate and oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a SQL query for get two table of SELECT.
**I want to get two table as entity in result.**
these tables are some column's name is equal(id,version).
I have following code :

```
String sql = "select sepTemp.*,pspTerm.* " +
            "from SEPTRANSACTIONTEMP sepTemp " +
            "LEFT JOIN PSP_Terminal pspTerm ON (pspTerm.idInPSP=sepTemp.termid AND pspTerm.pspID=:pspID) " +
            "where NOT EXISTS " +
            "(select * from PSPTRANSACTION pspTrans where pspTrans.PSPID=:pspID AND pspTrans.termNo=sepTemp.rrn) ";

    List<Object[]> sepTransactionTemps = em.createNativeQuery(sql)
            .setParameter("pspID", PSPTypes.SEP.getType())
            .getResultList();

 sepTransactionTemps.forEach(row -> {
                SEPTransactionTemp sepTransactionTemp = ((SEPTransactionTemp) row[0]);
                PSPTerminal sepTransactionTemp = ((PSPTerminal) row[1]);
...
```

but throw exception following :

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [ID] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663785/nonuniquediscoveredsqlaliasexception-when-two-table-has-same-column-names. May be you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

column id exists in your tables (SEPTRANSACTIONTEMP, LEFT JOIN PSP_Terminal)
create an alias for id column in your select query

```
    String sql = "select " + 
            "sepTemp.id as sepTemp_id, " + 
            "sepTemp.version as sepTemp_version, " +
            "pspTerm.id as pspTerm_id, " + 
            "pspTerm.version as pspTerm_version " // try here add all your column names 
        + " from SEPTRANSACTIONTEMP sepTemp LEFT JOIN PSP_Terminal pspTerm "
        + "ON (pspTerm.idInPSP=sepTemp.termid AND pspTerm.pspID=:pspID) " + "where NOT EXISTS "
        + "(select * from PSPTRANSACTION pspTrans where pspTrans.PSPID=:pspID AND pspTrans.termNo=sepTemp.rrn) ";


List<Object[]> sepTransactionTemps = em.createNativeQuery(sql).setParameter("pspID", PSPTypes.SEP.getType())
        .getResultList();
```

Comment: The number of columns is high

Comment: i regret telling you that this is the only way to achieve that

Comment: The brute force alternative is `ALTER TABLE .. RENAME COLUMN`